# Move files into local git repo branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I made some python notebooks. I also made a git repo. Those python notebooks aren't in the repo, they're in another directory. I want to create a branch in that repo, copy and paste those notebooks into that branch, then push that branch to my remote repo.

If I copy and paste the notebooks from the original directory and into the directory of the local repo, those notebooks seem to end up in my master branch. I don't want them on the master branch, I want them on my new branch, so I can merge with the master branch later on after code review.

How can I do this?

I'm using git Bash on Windows.

Comment: Did you try switching to (checking out) a new branch? `git switch -c my-new-branch`

Comment: Btw, if my previous comment works for you, then I think you can just delete this question, since you probably didn't realize you were simply asking how to create a branch, which is extremely well covered on SO, and elsewhere. (Also, `git switch -c` is nearly identical to `git checkout -b`.)

Comment: @TTT Yeah, I switched branch and then copied the files in, but still they end up on the master branch!

Comment: Did you commit them onto the new branch? If not then they'll follow your branch switches since they aren't on any branch yet.

Comment: It is not very clear exacly what you did. If you want people to be able to understand your situation, it would probably help if you stated the exact git commands you used to switch branch and to commit your changes to that branch, along with showing what your "git status" output is after you are done.